# Drawing in MIT-Scheme very slow

Tags: scheme, drawing

I've recently begun working through MIT's SICP-course and I'm having trouble with one of the old assignments found [here](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/psets/ps2/readme.html) on the official website.

The file *drawing.scm* includes a procedure *draw-connected* that takes a number as it's argument and returns another function. This function in turn takes a curve as it's argument (In this case a curve is any procedure that returns a specific point-object depending on a parameter t it is given)

```
(define (draw-connected n)
  (define window (make-graphics-device #f))
  (let ((1/n (/ 1 n)))
    (lambda (curve)
      (define (iter x-old y-old count)
        (let ((t (* count 1/n)))
        (let ((ct (curve t)))
          (let ((x-new (x-of ct))
                (y-new (y-of ct)))
            (graphics-draw-line
             window
             x-old
             y-old
             (exact->inexact x-new)
             (exact->inexact y-new))
            (if (>= count n)
                'done
                (iter x-new y-new (+ count 1)))))))
    (graphics-clear window)
    (let ((c0 (curve 0)))
      (iter (x-of c0) (y-of c0) 1)))))
```

I slightly modified *draw-connected* so I could invoke it more easily (originally *window* was not defined in the procedure but given to it as a parameter).
Now, when I invoke this procedure by opening the respective .scm file in a buffer in edwin, evaluating it and then evaluating

```
((draw-connected 20) foo)
```

A separate window opens and after a delay of about 20 seconds a crude graph of the function *foo* consisting of *n* connected plot points appears. For greater values of *n* this takes even longer.

Is this normal? Is it just that *draw-connected* does not work efficiently?
Would it help if I somehow compiled the sourcecode first?

Would be great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Was it faster before your modification?